# Inefficient code: Prevent generation of duplicate random numbers

Tags: random, lua, duplicates

I have some code from a larger program. This part generate random numbers within a range and checks for duplicates. I have placed print statement to help with getting a handle on scope. If a duplicate is detected I want a new random number to be generated. The code works but I think an experience programmer would laugh at how ineptly it does it. So I was hoping for some guidance on how to improve this code.

[Code Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5wFY.png)

Comment: You might want to take this to the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: This question as currently presented would be off-topic on Code Review, as the code to be reviewed must be __included in the question__ (rather than a screenshot/image of it). Besides that, if the code works as intended and the author is looking for improvements, Code Review would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- prepare set of numbers to choose from
local r = {}
for i = c-8, c+12 do
   table.insert(r, i)
end
-- take some numbers from the set
for i = 1, #options do
   options[i] = table.remove(r, math.random(#r))
end
-- options[] is guaranteed to not contain duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative for when you're only going to pull a few numbers from a large set and place them in `options`. It *might* be a tad faster than Egor's in that situation. For the following, assume the random number between integer `A` and integer `B`, and you're looking for `C` unique numbers:

```
options = {}
local taken = {}
for i = 1,C do
  repeat
    options[i] = math.random(A,B)
  while taken[options[i]] ~= nil
  taken[options[i]] = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve it by setting an array to record whether a number has already been added or not. Here is a sample pseudo-code.

```
//create a list whichs length is the num of possible numbers
numAddedState <- createList((upperBound-lowerBound+1),false)

generatedNums <- []

while length(generatedNums) < requiredLength {
    num <- random(lowerBound, upperBound)
    if (numAddedState[num - lowerBound]) {
        //add the number into list and change the added state of this number to true
        generatedNums.append(num)
        numAddedState[num - lowerBound] <- true
    }
    else {
        print(num + " is dup")
    }
}
return generatedNums
```

if you need to generate float point numbers, you can replace the numAddedState list with a list of list, which stores grouped numbers. By doing that you can reduce the num of item you need to check.
Here is an example which group numbers using floor()

```
//create a list whichs length is the num of possible numbers and default value is an empty list
numsAdded <- createList((floor(upperBound)-floor(lowerBound+1)),[])

generatedNums <- []

while length(generatedNums) < requiredLength {
    num <- random(lowerBound, upperBound) //generate float point number
    for numbers in numsAdded[floor(num)] {
        if numbers == num {
            print(num + " is dup")
            continue
        }
    }

    numsAdded[floor(num)].append(num)
    generatedNums.append(num)
}
return generatedNums
```